# syntax error, invalid character when declaring constants

Tags: java

In my code I declared the below posted constants. but eclipse marked them with red, with error message :

```
syntax error, invalid character
```

please let me know why i am getting this error, and how to solve it.

**constants**:

```
private final static int CONST_MASTER_CARD_MIN_1 = 222100​;
private final static int CONST_MASTER_CARD_MAX_1 = 272099;
private final static int CONST_MASTER_CARD_MIN_2 = 510000​;
private final static int CONST_MASTER_CARD_MAX_2 = ​559999;
```

Comment: You have an invisible space character before your semi-colons. Delete the semi-colon and the last digit, and re-type them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have special hidden character in your code, I passed your code to [ideone](https://ideone.com/JUBA2p) and I note this :

[image: Special hidden characters]

Note the red point which is a special hidden character.

Instead Use this :

```
private final static int CONST_MASTER_CARD_MIN_1 = 222100;
private final static int CONST_MASTER_CARD_MAX_1 = 272099;
private final static int CONST_MASTER_CARD_MIN_2 = 510000;
private final static int CONST_MASTER_CARD_MAX_2 = 559999;
```

[Ideone correct code](https://ideone.com/2OmucR)